# How to prevent IPython close with Ctrl-C

Tags: python, ipython

I run a python script from within ipython using "run script.py". When I stop the script with Ctrl-C and use the command (accidentally) twice, IPython will close. How can i deactivate that IPython closes with Ctrl-C ?

Thank you.

Comment: That's odd, it shouldn't exit no matter how many times you hit Ctrl-C. Is it possible that you hit Ctrl-D instead? Ctrl-D twice when there's a prompt will exit. If you can reproduce it with Ctrl-C, what platform are you on and is your IPython up to date/

Comment: I am using Anaconda python 3.5 on a windows 7 machine. I realised, that it is not due to the script. IPython will close even when using Ctrl-C twice in the terminal.

Comment: Can you [file an issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues) about that?